# Adjusting hyperlinks in svg file

Tags: email, svg, xml-signature

I am new here and facing problem while adjusting my exported svg file from Illustrator. I am trying to make it clickable (to link e-mail and Social Media Icons) but I am still not there. To linked yet. Can you please help me, to find the mistake? I know, it would be much more easier to code it by myself, although I am new and don't have enough experience for doing it. Thank you very much!

Sending the code, see mostly the end where are the slices I marked in the img in Illustrator and have to link.

Thanks a bunch!

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 22.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 850.4 566.9" style="enable-background:new 0 0 850.4 566.9;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:none;}
</style>

<rect id="_x3C_Slice_x3E_"><a xlink:href="https://www.xxxs.com/">x="423" y="237.9" class="st0" width="253" height="32"</a>/></rect>
<rect id="_x3C_Slice_x3E__1_"><a xlink:href="https://www.xxxx.com/">x="152" y="392.9" class="st0" width="271" height="29"</a>/></rect>
<rect id="_x3C_Slice_x3E__2_"><a xlink:href="https://www.xxxx/">x="580" y="295.9" class="st0" width="29" height="23"</a>/></rect>
<rect id="_x3C_Slice_x3E__3_"><a xlink:href="https://xxxx/">x="609" y="295.9" class="st0" width="20" height="23"</a>/></rect>
<rect id="_x3C_Slice_x3E__4_"><a xlink:href="https://xxx/">x="629" y="295.9" class="st0" width="25" height="23"</a>/></rect>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<a>` should go round the `<rect>` I changed the fill as well, otherwise all your rect elements are invisible.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 22.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 850.4 566.9" style="enable-background:new 0 0 850.4 566.9;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
 .st0{fill:blue;}
</style>

<a xlink:href="https://www.xxxs.com/"><rect id="_x3C_Slice_x3E_" x="423" y="237.9" class="st0" width="253" height="32"/></a>
<a xlink:href="https://www.xxxx.com/"><rect id="_x3C_Slice_x3E__1_" x="152" y="392.9" class="st0" width="271" height="29"/></a>
<a xlink:href="https://www.xxxx/"><rect id="_x3C_Slice_x3E__2_" x="580" y="295.9" class="st0" width="29" height="23"/></a>
<a xlink:href="https://xxxx/"><rect id="_x3C_Slice_x3E__3_" x="609" y="295.9" class="st0" width="20" height="23"/></a>
<a xlink:href="https://xxx/"><rect id="_x3C_Slice_x3E__4_" x="629" y="295.9" class="st0" width="25" height="23"/></a>
```